# Размещение нескольких элементов в видимой области ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

Есть данный макет. Область на которой находятся `Card`'ы. При свайпе справа-налево должны отображться следующие 2 элемента. Я делаю это с помощью `ViewPager`, но проблема в том, что ViewPager размещает по одному элементу в видимую область. Как решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разместите в элементе ViewPager 2 карда.

Comment: Вам нужно сделать одну страницу ViewPager в которой содержится два CardView (а не один) и так для каждой страницы

Comment: у меня есть лист объектов , которые должны по 2 отображаться во viewPager , как реализовать именно то, чтобы из листа бралось по 2 элемента

Comment: А не пробовали с помощью RecyclerView реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не претендую на завершенное решение, но кажется должна сработать такая идея.

Все карды кладутся в горизонтальный `LinearLayout`, который оборачивается в `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        orientation="horizontal"
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Card>…</Card>
        <Card>…</Card>
        …
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Это даст нам возможность скроллить карды по горизонтали.

Теперь нужно изменить ширину кардов так, чтобы на экран помещалось два карда. Для этого можно, например, унаследоваться от `Card` и переопределить `onMeasure`:

```
public class MyCard extends Card {
    // …

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {

        final View parentScrollView = ((View)(getParent().getParent()));

        if (parentScrollView != null) {
            if (parentScrollView instanceof HorizontalScrollView) {
                widthMeasureSpec = parentScrollView.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            }
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Останется по событию скролла вычислить ближайшую позицию скролла, в которой на экране будут отображаться два карда целиком и вручную доскроллить через `HorizontalScrollView.fullScroll(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

В адаптере переопредели метод `getCount`, чтобы он возвращал половину от размера твоего списка.

```
private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return Fragment1.newInstance(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (int) (myList.size()/2);
}
}
```

А в самом фрагменте в методе `onCreateView`, из полученной позиции, возьмешь два элемента из списка. Допустим у тебя страница 3, соответственно возьмешь элементы 5 и 6 из списка.